# Show just particular parts of website - select via CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

what would be the easiest method to display only specific elements on a website?
For example, on a news site only the headlines and nothing else.

I'd like to select elements via CSS so only those should be displayed.
I tried to use the `:not` pseudoclass:

```
:not(.myClass) { display: none; }
```

But obviously, the parents of the `.myClass`-elements aren't displayed and so aren't them.
Do you know any possibility to achieve this? It doesn't have to be CSS-only, Javascript is possible too.
A web-app that does this would also be great.

I'd like to be able to filter some sites I visit, so I would apply this as a user-stylesheet.

Comment: I wouldn't lean on CSS3 selectors with no IE support if I were you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the page with [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and easily select the elements you want...

```
$("body").load("path/to/page.html div.headline");
```

The above will load all `<div class="headline">` elements into the body of the document.

Note: You will of course have to keep the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show only the news headline you will need to structure your HTML correctly. If you have a container div the easiest way to do this would be to apply a secondary class to it and show/hide elements trough that class:

```
<div class="container news_page">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Random text I want to hide.<p>
<div class="random_container">Another random element i want to hide.</div>
</div>

.container {border:1px solid red;} /* .container has normal styling */
.news_page p, .news_page .random_container {display:none;} /* .news_page is used only to select elements inside container on news page */
```

This would be the css only solution to this.

Comment: `:not` **is** a CSS selector - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not

Comment: Yeah - my bad - I guess I do to much things with jQuery. Corrected. But note that :not won't work in IE since it is CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out how to comment on things, so as a response to the last answer's last comment, check this out: http://selectivizr.com/. It *says* it can emulate CSS3 selectors for IE, so maybe that will fix your problems with Exploder...